# php str_replace syntax error

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm trying to build a `createCDATASection` string with str_replace but can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I want to end up with:

```
$popUpUrl = "javascript:display('http://mySite/profile?sessionCode=588A9F34-DBF3-4806-8814-37CFC72C6F71', 600, 2000);";
$cdata = $dom->createCDATASection($popUpUrl);
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$popUpUrl = "javascript:display('http://mySite/profile?sessionCode={sessionCode}', 600, 2000);"
$popUpUrl = str_replace('{sessionCode}', '588A9F34-DBF3-4806-8814-37CFC72C6F71', $popUpUrl);
$cdata = $dom->createCDATASection($popUpUrl);
```

This gives the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$popUpUrl' (T_VARIABLE)
```

on the line

```
$popUpUrl = str_replace('{sessionCode}', '588A9F34-DBF3-4806-8814-37CFC72C6F71', $popUpUrl);
```

Comment: What does *not working* mean? Do you get any errors ? Looks good to me

Comment: Apologies, I get a syntax error. I've edited the question.

Comment: There's a semicolon (;) missing at the end of line 1

Comment: @Reeno - d'oh! That's why this isn't working but there's another issue. I'll create another question for it though.

Comment: @Reeno: if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is quite simple: There's a semicolon missing at the end of line 1. PHP notes the error in line 2, because line 1 never ends and PHP notices the error  not until line 2.

Comment: Cheers - I'll slope off sheepishly now. =)